# Density function without using convolution

Tags: probability

I have the following joint density function:

$$ f_{X,Y}(x,y) = (y-x)e^{-y} (0<x<y) $$

I want to find the density of X + Y.

I find the density of X and Y integrating:

$$f_X(x) = e^{-x} (0<x<\infty)$$
$$ f_Y(y) = \frac{y^2}{2}e^{-y} (0<y<\infty)$$

So I find that X and Y are not indented and thus I cannot find the density of the sum using convolution. My idea is then to find:

$$ F_{X+Y}(t) =  \mathbb{P}[X + Y \leq t] $$ and then integrating to find the density.

I think I made a mistake setting up this double integral though:

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{y}^{t-y} (y-x)e^{-y}dxdi $$

Is this right? I am not getting the result I should.

EDIT:
I also tried doing it with this formula:

$$ f_{X+Y}(t) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,t-x)dx $$  But I didn't manage to solve this. Plus even here I am not too sure about the integration extremes, I have done the integral from $0$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta), we can obtain the density of $Z=g(X,\,Y)$ as the definite integral $f_Z(z):=\int f_{X,\,Y}(x,\,y)\delta(g(x,\,y)-z)dxdy$, where the integration range is the support of the joint density $f_{X,\,Y}$. In the case at hand, with $z=x+y\ge 2x$,$$f_Z(z)=\int (y-x)e^{-y}\delta(x+y-z)dxdy,$$where again I haven't shown the integration range. Where you need to know your Dirac delta onions is in integrating out $y$:$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^{z/2}(z-2x)e^{x-z}dx=e^{-z}(2e^{z/2}-2-z).$$